# Payload Error while Deploying Global Value Set with Language Translations in Production

Tags: deployment, translation, global-picklist

I have a Custom Object that includes a Picklist which uses Global Value Set. Now, while deploying this to Production, it's giving me Payload Error while validating the Change Set.

> Missing feature, Details: Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Language Translation

My Change Set only contains the **Picklist Field**, **Global Value Set**, and the **Language Translations**. The Custom Object is already deployed in Production.

Is there a reason why I am unable to deploy this? TIA

Comment: You may need to enable translations in translations in the target org?

Comment: Okay, somehow the Translations were disabled in Target org and I was dumb enough to not to check that. Silly mistake. Thank you @Ranga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Issue was that I didn't check whether the Translations are Enabled in my Target Org.

You can set that by Going to Setup > Translation Setting > Enable.